# converting an string into and array

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter application, I have an string like this `{"value": "2310", "label": "Root >> test" },{"value": "2314", "label": "Root >> TV >> test" }` and I want to convert it in an array like this:

```
[2310] => Root >> test
[2314] => Root >> TV >> test
```

Please tell how can I do that?

Comment: Have you stripped stuff off that snippet? Is it actually JSON?

Comment: The json you showed is incorrect (missing`[]`)

Comment: Rolled back edit since we can't be sure that the string is meant to be JSON yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json decode it, then assign to a results array: https://3v4l.org/NS8d0

```
<?php

$x = json_decode('[{"value": "2310", "label": "Root >> test" },{"value": "2314", "label": "Root >> TV >> test" }]', true);

$results = [];

foreach($x as $y) {
    $results[$y['value']] = $y['label'];
}

var_dump($results);
```

Which will give you the array you need.

> Note. I had to surround your JSON string with `[` and `]` to get this to work. Possibly you just didn't paste that?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like JSON. In which case, you can do this:

```
$arr = json_decode($string); //assuming your json is in a variable called $string.
```